# Spring data mongo db query on inner fields of embedded document (DBRef)

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a a document which is having references of two other document. I have to query in the basis of id of UserLogin and shopmaster. How I can achieve this. Please suggest how to query.

```
@Id
private String userShopAssociationId;

@DBRef
private UserLogin userLogin;

@DBRef
private ShopMaster shopMaster;

Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userLogin.$id").is(userShopAssociationForm.getUserLoginId()));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("shopMaster.$id").is(userShopAssociationForm.getShopMasterId());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The queries that you have look correct; you should be able to query based on the `_id` of a DBRef. That's because a DBRef stores the collection, id, and (sometimes) the database on the parent document. However, you might need to convert the ids you are comparing to an `ObjectId` like so:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userLogin.$id").is(new ObjectId(userShopAssociationForm.getUserLoginId())));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("shopMaster.$id").is(new ObjectId(userShopAssociationForm.getShopMasterId()));
```

Comment: and if not a dbref?